# regular expression for sentence

Tags: regex

Please help me for regular expression of string like this `sp13-bse-018`.

I've got the following inputs:

- starts with `fa` or `sp`
- Followed by 2 digits and `-`
- Then `bcs`, `btn` or `bse`
- `-` and 3 digits

I have make this regular expression

```
^((\SP)|(sp)|(FA)|(fa))[1-9][0-9]{2}-{0,1}((BSE)|(bse)|(bcs)|(BCS)|(BTN)|(btn))-{0,1}[0-9]{3}$
```

but this is not working properly and i also have a lot search for this but i cant get it.

I will be highly thankful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the culprit is the obligatory non-zero digit  `[1-9]`, and once you remove it, your regex will work.

You may shorten your pattern by removing unnecessary groups and using a case insensitive flag:

```
/^(sp|fa)[0-9]{2}-?(bse|bcs|btn)-?[0-9]{3}$/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wF3rD8/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(sp|fa)` - either `sp` or `fa`
- `[0-9]{2}` - two ASCII digits
- `-?` - an optional (due to `?`) hyphen
- `(bse|bcs|btn)` - either `bse` or `bcs` or `btn`
- `-?` - an optional hyphen
- `[0-9]{3}` - 3 ASCII digits
- `$`  - end of string.

The case insensitive flag will also allow matching `Sp`, `sP`, so if you do not want that behavior, use more alternation: `(sp|fa)` -> `(sp|SP|fa|FA)`, etc.

Comment: Thank u so much . Its working but I have to allow upper case letters.

Comment: So, use the case insensitive flag. What is your environment?

Comment: Thank u so much . Its very helpful